# MySQL select product which is in both categories

Tags: mysql, select

### products

```
PRODUCTID;NAME
1        ;BMW
2        ;AUDI
3        ;Mercedes
4        ;Volvo
```

### productCategories

```
CATID;CATNAME
1    ;Car
2    ;Motorcicle;
3    ;Bus
```

### productCategiresRel

```
PRODUCTID;CATID;
1        ;1
1        ;2
2        ;1
3        ;1
4        ;3
```

if I use SQL

```
SELECT productID FROM  productCategiresRel WHERE catID IN (1,2)
```

the result is

```
productCategiresRel
PRODUCTID;CATID;
1        ;1
1        ;2
2        ;1
3        ;1
4        ;3
```

but I want the to select these products which is represented in both select categories (Car and Motorcicle).

The result should be:

```
PRODUCTID;CATID;
1        ;1 (Car)
1        ;2 (Motorcicle)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an `EXISTS` to check multiple times.

```
SELECT *
FROM products
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT '' 
    FROM productCategiresRel 
    WHERE catID = 1
    AND productCategiresRel.productId = products.productId)
AND EXISTS (SELECT '' 
    FROM productCategiresRel 
    WHERE catID = 2
    AND productCategiresRel.productId = products.productId)
```

Answer (score 0):

Or if you want to find all products that are in multiple categories--not just in Categories 1 and 2-- try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM products
WHERE productID IN (
    SELECT productID
    FROM productCategiresRel
    GROUP BY productID
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
);
```